# On how to interpret paired comparisons for model-adjusted means in GLMM

Tags: glmm, lsmeans

I have been trying to learn how to obtain the model-adjusted means (or least-square means) from GLMM, and come across some counterintuitive results.

Below is the data I am currently using. It's the number of seeds contained in each of 20 fruits harvested from 6 plants. Each fruit was assigned to either of the 4 different treatments, A to D. Distance from each plant to its nearest neighbor was measured, too.

```
d <- data.frame(Seed=c(801,7,0,1255,5922,8,5,927,2098,7,72,72,26,159,944,5,4,440,2510,0), 
Fruit=c(264,302,595, 223,1548,459,365,361,598,378,249,376,656,337,673,411,135,209,1203,305), 
Plant=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6), 
Treatment=c("A","B","C","A","B","C","D","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","D","A","B","C"), 
Distance=c(5.97,5.97,5.97,13.60,13.60,13.60,13.60,87.30,87.30,87.30,99.30,99.30,99.30,105.00,105.00,105.00,105.00,120.10,120.10,120.10))

> d
   Seed Fruit Plant Treatment Distance
1   801   264     1         A     5.97
2     7   302     1         B     5.97
3     0   595     1         C     5.97
4  1255   223     2         A    13.60
5  5922  1548     2         B    13.60
6     8   459     2         C    13.60
7     5   365     2         D    13.60
8   927   361     3         A    87.30
9  2098   598     3         B    87.30
10    7   378     3         C    87.30
11   72   249     4         A    99.30
12   72   376     4         B    99.30
13   26   656     4         C    99.30
14  159   337     5         A   105.00
15  944   673     5         B   105.00
16    5   411     5         C   105.00
17    4   135     5         D   105.00
18  440   209     6         A   120.10
19 2510  1203     6         B   120.10
20    0   305     6         C   120.10
```

First, I compared the number of seeds per fruit among different treatments, using glmer() in R package lme4. Distance was used as a covariate, and Plant was used as a random effect.

```
library(lme4)
glmm.fit <- glmer(Seed ~ Treatment + Distance + (1|Plant), offset=log(Fruit), family=poisson(link=log), data=d)
```

Second, I calculated the model-adjusted means of number of seeds per fruit for each treatment, using lsmeans() in package lsmeans.

```
library(lsmeans)
lsm <- lsmeans(glmm.fit, ~ Treatment, transform="response")
```

Then I got this:

```
> lsm
 Treatment   rate     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 A         1.6711 0.5724 Inf    0.5492    2.7930
 B         1.4371 0.4920 Inf    0.4728    2.4014
 C         0.0134 0.0050 Inf    0.0036    0.0231
 D         0.0081 0.0039 Inf    0.0005    0.0158

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

As you can see, the obtained 95% CIs of the model-adjusted means overlap between the treatments A vs. B, and C vs. B.

```
> plot(lsm)
```

[image]

However, when I performed significance tests for paired comparisons using pairs() in package lsmeans as follows, I got this:

```
plsm <- pairs(lsm)

> plsm
 contrast estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 A - B      0.2340 0.0861 Inf 2.717   0.0334 
 A - C      1.6577 0.5678 Inf 2.919   0.0184 
 A - D      1.6629 0.5696 Inf 2.919   0.0184 
 B - C      1.4237 0.4874 Inf 2.921   0.0183 
 B - D      1.4289 0.4892 Inf 2.921   0.0183 
 C - D      0.0052 0.0038 Inf 1.375   0.5151

P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates
```

The above significance tests show that there are significant differences among treatments, except between C and D. Considering that the 95% CIs overlap between A and B (see above graph), however, the result seems contradictory to me. How does that happen?

I guess I am doing wrong or misinterpreting the results at some point. I've checked the document "using lsmeans", but couldn't figure how I am wrong. I would greatly appreciate if anyone could help me on this, thank you!

Comment: A and B have high positive correlation.

Comment: Thanks! I figured that the SE of a difference between A and B (0.0861) became small because of the high correlation between the means estimated for A and B.

Comment: I have one more question. I would definitely report the results of the pairwise test (i.e., A and B differ significantly). But I also want to know how to show it visually. Showing the 95% CIs (above graph) is misleading, apparently. Could anyone tell me how to illustrate the model adjusted means for A to D and the results of pairwise comparisons in the same figure in an unequivocal way?

Comment: OK, I just found out the vignette topics for R package emmeans
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/basics.html#more

Looks like it will answer my question.

Comment: I’ll add this: Don’t ever use overlapping CIs to do comparisons. Even without the correlation structure you have, it is misleading.

Comment: @bbKZO I'm curious if you find the `pwpp()` function useful. It's a new idea, and I added it fairly recently. Probably should write a paper about it.

Comment: @rvl, thank you for your comments! OK, the CIs are not what I should be looking at when comparing between two treatments, whether or not high correlation exists.

What I'm not quite sure is whether it applies to GLM too. I mean, should I avoid using CIs of least-square means even when random effect is not included in the model? If so, what's the point of showing CIs as outputs of emmeans() in the first place?

Comment: @rvl, as for your second comment, I do like the idea of "pairwise P-value plot" obtained from pwpp() function. It could circumvent the use of CIs and shows everything you need to understand the results. Actually I am thinking to use this type of plot for my paper. But I prefer to have the least-square means as visual objects, not like the digits in the current pwpp format. I might display a horizontal bar plot of least-square means without error bars on the left side of the pairwise P-value plot.

Comment: Side-by-side CIs *are* useful for showing the means and their margins of error. They just aren’t useful for testing comparisons between them.

Comment: OK, I understand. Thanks for clarification!